# Are bifurcations in dynamical systems related to phase transitions?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, chaos-theory, non-linear-systems, bifurcation

Bifurcation is a qualitative measure for a dynamical system changing the system parameter. Does the statistical behavior in the system shows phase transition-like characteristics?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, similarly to the divergent susceptibility of [continuous phase transitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_transition#Modern_classifications), there are statistical analyses of the systems behavior that can reveal it's approaching a bifurcation.

Typically, structurally stable systems return exponentially to equilibrium states. Close to a bifurcation, the systems is *not* structurally stable - i.e, a small change in a parameter might cause a qualitative change - and the return to equilibrium is slower. This can be observed directly or through its effect on the statistics of noise-induced fluctuations.

The observation of such early warning signs is not without challenges, though (see, e.g., [Which System Variables Carry Robust Early Signs of Upcoming Phase Transition?](https://dx.doi.org/10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0163003)), and the methods mentioned might miss whole classes of transitions (see, e.g., [Early warning signs for saddle-escape transitions in complex networks](https://dx.doi.org/10.1038%2Fsrep13190)).